# Create windows installer package for JavaEE application with Java Beans

Tags: glassfish, javabeans, java-ee-6, netbeans-7

I have a `Java EE` project with java beans that's run on `Glassfish` server. I need to create a windows installer package of the project. Can someone tell me how to do this.?

Comment: Buy [InstallShield](http://www.installshield.com) or learn [InnoSetup](http://www.jrsoftware.org/isinfo.php‎).  But typically, J2EE projects are packaged and deployed as an EAR file (or similar), not a Windows "setup.msi"...

Comment: Developers develop to Java EE these days, not J2EE ;-)  In addition, Java EE allows EJBs to be packaged into .war files. That being said, the tooling approach is good.